# Instantiate an object separately for shared pointer C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

The below code works fine:

```
std::map<std::string,std::ofstream*> m_jsTabFilesMap;
m_jsTabFilesMap.insert({ listOfTabNames[i], new std::ofstream(jsFilename)});
```

But if I replace normal pointer with a shared pointer the insert function complaints no overloaded version of the function `insert()` exists.

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>> m_jsTabFilesMap;
```

How do I fix this ? Has it to do with the way I'm instantiating the object using new.

Comment: Are you still using `m_jsTabFilesMap.insert({ listOfTabNames[i], new std::ofstream(jsFilename)});` when you change it to `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>> m_jsTabFilesMap;`?

Answer (score 8):

The constructor of `std::shared_ptr<T>` which takes a `T*` is `explicit`, and with good reason. Implicitly creating an owning smart pointer when a raw pointer is passed in would be asking for trouble.

This means you must change the way you insert into the function. To remain exception-safe, raw pointer -> smart pointer conversions should generally happen one at a time, or through functions. In your case, it's probably for the best to use `std::make_shared`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>> m_jsTabFilesMap;
m_jsTabFilesMap.insert({ listOfTabNames[i], std::make_shared<std::ofstream>(jsFilename)});
```